# Remove all console.log before deploying nodejs app to production?

Tags: node.js, console.log

The question may be asked before. I am about to deploy a nodejs 10.16 app to production with `pm2` installed. Here is the [article](https://hashnode.com/post/10-things-you-shouldnt-do-while-running-nodejs-in-production-cisab2fyu0s9oth5341faywcw) about what NOT to do for nodejs deployment:

```
Not removing console.log statements

While developing an app, we use console.log statements to test things out. But sometimes we forget to remove these log statements in production, which consume the CPU time and waste the resources. The best way to avoid this is to use debug module. So, unless you start your app with environment variable DEBUG nothing will be printed to the console.
```

There is no further details about what to do if I would like to receive the error output on the console screen for monitoring and debug purpose. Since there are many lines of `console.log` in my code in development. Do I have to remove them all before deploying to production? What is the standard practice about the console.log in production environment?

Comment: You would usually not display the logs in the terminal. Logs are saved either locally (on the prod) to be later examined if there's any problem, or they are consumed by other services/API to be saved in the database, either again on the same machine, or remotely send it somewhere else. Check out [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_file). Plus, you can check this popular npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

Comment: You can use some npm package for that.

Comment: Personally, I usually setup a service for logging that checks an environment boolean to see if it's in "debug" mode. If it's not, it forgo's all console.log ... but it gives me the ability to flip it on should I need to troubleshoot an issue an end-user has. An added benefit is it gives you a great deal of control over your logging if used consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach may be to wrap console.log in your app and only display "logs" if environment is "development".

Another way, if you are in a hurry is to add this to the top of your `server.js` or similar (after the require statements):

```
console.log = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-console